# Why is Campaign Monitor responding with error "310: HTML Content URL Required" even though I have provided the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm using the [CreateSend API gem](https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-ruby), and in my **local dev** environment I am able to successfully create a draft campaign.

In **production (staging), on Heroku**, the exact same code instead returns with an error:

```
310: HTML Content URL Required
```

I am definitely passing the HTML content URL, as well as all the other required arguments to `Campaign.create` (I've visually verified the fact by logging the variables). Here's the API call:

```
cm_campaign_id = CreateSend::Campaign.create client_id, subject, name, from_name, from_email, reply_to, html_url, text_url, list_ids, segment_ids
```

Furthermore, in local dev the API call returns in less than 3 seconds, whereas on Heroku it times out for 30 seconds and returns that error.

Why is this happening on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because their API requires a second request to your app to happen in the middle of a first ongoing request, I suggest you move the logic off to a worker process:

1. the request to your app  that creates a campaign does not talk to Campaign Monitor, instead it just creates a job in a table, and redirects to a page that checks the status of that job
2. a worker dyno sees the job and starts working on it, posting to the Campaign Monitor API… because this is not a web dyno, it's not a problem for it to wait
3. the CM API will then request the newsletter pages and respond back to the worker dyno
4. the worker dyno can then update the status of the job
5. all the while, the page you redirected to in the first step can continue refreshing itself polling the job's status, and show the final page once it notices the job has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **[look at @kch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397004/664833)**.

I was getting the error `310: HTML Content URL Required` when running one web dyno.

Here are the relevant logs:

```
2012-07-04T19:11:13+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> POST my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/campaigns dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-07-04T19:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss
2012-07-04T19:11:13+00:00 heroku[router]: GET my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=50ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-07-04T19:11:14+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/newsletters/1?cm=1 dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-07-04T19:11:14+00:00 app[web.1]: [error] CampaignMonitor error: The CreateSend API responded with the following error - 310: HTML Content URL Required
```

Seeing the `Request timeout` error on `GET my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/newsletters/1?cm=1` made me recall that Campaign Monitor was immediately calling back my app for all the newsletter assets.

When I increased the number of web dynos to two, sometimes the error changed to `312: Text Content URL Required` and it would timeout on `GET my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/newsletters/1.txt`; other times (still with two dynos) the API would not error out (the campaign draft was actually created), but the app timed-out on other assets (and the site still produced the stock `Application Error`). Here are some of those asset timeouts:

```
2012-07-04T19:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> POST my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/campaigns dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-07-04T19:20:24+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/assets/video/play.png dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-07-04T19:20:24+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/assets/video/pause.png dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

When I increased the number of web dynos to three, there were still asset timeouts.

With *four web dynos*, the whole process sometimes completed successfully (i.e. not always!) -- anyway, even if it was always successful, four dynos would be too expensive just to create Campaign Monitor newsletters.

---

**assets on CDN**

I have converted my app to [use a CDN asset host](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31) (Amazon S3) thanks to [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) and fog, and I have returned to this problem: using Campaign Monitor from Heroku.

Since my app no longer serves assets (they are served by Amazon S3), essentially all it is responsible for is returning HTML.

In terms of Campaign Monitor, the moment you query their API to create a *campaign* based on your *newsletter*, they immediately call you back to download your newsletter. This actually means that they send two *parallel* requests: one for the HTML version of the newsletter, and one for the TEXT version of the newsletter. With one dyno blocked by the original call to their API, and with all assets hosted on a CDN, you'd think that a second dyno would do the trick. In fact, I have seen a single second dyno handle the "parallel" requests (for the HTML and TEXT versions of the newsletter). But it is unreliable, as there still are random timeouts (`Error H12 (Request timeout)`):

```
2012-08-16T23:00:42+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> POST my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/campaigns dyno=web.2 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-08-16T23:00:42+00:00 heroku[router]: GET my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.4 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-08-16T23:00:42+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET my-app-1111.herokuapp.com/newsletters/1?cm=1 dyno=web.2 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-08-16T23:00:43+00:00 app[web.2]: [error] CampaignMonitor error: The CreateSend API responded with the following error - 310: HTML Content URL Required
```

Heroku's support says that this is because they *dispatch each request independently, on the expectation that eventually the receiving dyno will be able to handle it. What's happening here is that in some cases, the same dyno that is making the post is the one that's receiving the second request, but it seems it needs the result from the second request to complete the post request, so it deadlocks.*

---

**solutions**

One possible *interim* solution is to use `unicorn` for your app server, with two unicorn `worker_processes`. That way even if Heroku dispatches to the busy dyno, the second unicorn listener will respond to the request.

Ultimately though, and in addition to using `unicorn` with two `worker_processes`, the correct solution is to *handle the request asynchronously*, by something like `delayed_job`, and use `workless` to spin up Heroku worker dynos on a per-need basis, so you only pay for what you use.

Comment: Hi, like you've mentioned Campaign Monitor will immediately download and parse both the HTML and text content of your campaign. When parsing the HTML content we'll download all linked assets with some degree of parallelism (depending on load at the time) which is why you're still seeing timeouts with only 2 or 3 dynos.

Obviously this is just the current implementation and may change, but suffice to say, we'll always try and download your assets in parallel.

Comment: @Toby I have updated my answer to say that a Heroku app hosting assets on a CDN requires a minimum of 3 web dynos to use Campaign Monitor. This fact should probably be near the top of your docs somewhere, as it implies substantial fees.